# Can I make an animation in the blender game engine but still move the object how I want?

Tags: game-engine

I'm making a go kart game and I need an opponent. I tried some things but they where all too difficult for me. Now I want to give the kart an animation so that it succesfully drives over the parcours. But I want to be able to push the kart around with mine so that it can be pushed of the road but that it tries to align itself again.

Comment: I haven't tried anything similar to answer this but I have an idea you might try. Animate an invisible cube and make your enemy AI racer always track to this cube as a dynamic object. Then you 'll be able to push it. But you need to make sure the cube slows down a bit when your player hits the AI else it might get so fast that the AI will start moving backwards. That's only an idea.

Comment: I wouldn't do this with animation, I would want the kart to have a steering brick that always goes toward an empty that represents where it should be driving on the track.